# How to lookup any index from Yahoo using pandas-datareader

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo, datareader, ticker

I want to use look ups for any online index, including those with digits. A random example is:

https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/YSM6.AX/futures?p=YSM6.AX

A naive method is to use pandas-datareader:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as datareader
online_data = datareader.DataReader('YSM6.AX', 'yahoo', start, end)
```

However, this doesn't work. I think the digits in the ticker aren't handled properly. This command works fine with e.g. "AAPL".

How do I get this to work for any index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YSM6.AX link shows that there is no data for this stock.
If you want to grab multiple stock, and get specifically the adjusted close, you can use this code. It takes into account any funny stock tickers that have either a "-", or in the case of YSM6.AX, a "." inside the ticker.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    from pandas_datareader import data, wb
    tickers = ["BRK.B", "AAPL", "MSFT", "YHOO", "JPM"]
    series_list = []

    start = datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 5)
    end = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 28)
    for security in tickers:
        s = data.DataReader(security.replace(".","-"),"yahoo",start, end )["Adj Close"]

        s.name = security
        series_list.append(s)

    df = pd.concat(series_list, axis=1)

    stocks= pd.DataFrame(df)
    stocks
```

Comment: Thank you Michael.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the link you have provided, YSM6 is a futures contract on ASX.  Specifically it is the M6 expiry, meaning 2016-06.  And Yahoo has no data for this contract on their site anymore--perhaps because it is expired, or perhaps because there was never any data available for it.  Furthermore, this product (3 year AU interest rate swap futures) seems to have been discontinued by the exchange.

Your question says you want "stock" data.  Here's an example of an actual stock with a numeric symbol:

https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/7203.KL/?p=7203.KL

Comment: Thanks John, very prompt and helpful reply. You answered my question correctly but I was amending whilst you were answering. My apologies, I am still fairly new to this.

Comment: I rolled back to the original question and accepted your answer. Thanks.